# Call a number from an activity over the lock screen?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an activity displayed without unlocking a user's phone. Is it possible to initiate a phone call from this activity while still being locked?

Intent.ACTION_CALL or Intent.ACTION_DIAL both ask to unlock the phone rather than making the call.

Comment: No. This is part of Android's security measures. You can't bypass them like that.

Comment: @TheWanderer That's a shame. Is a SMS possible?

Comment: No. If it were, why have a lock method at all, if anyone could just send texts or make phone calls straight from the lockscreen?

Comment: @TheWanderer Well it is possible, I just did it. I don't see the problem when you have to ask for the permission.

Comment: right, sorry, you can send SMS from the lock screen, but you can't make calls.